# Browse Corda database tables using H2 web interface shows synonyms errors

Tags: h2, corda

I followed the instructions at [this](https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html#node-database) link to browse corda database.
However, I am getting below errors when I queried for tables.

[image: Image having error screenshot]

**Error:**

```
Table "SYNONYMS" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_CAT, TYPE_SCHEM, 
TYPE_NAME, SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, REF_GENERATION, SQL FROM (SELECT SYNONYM_CATALOG TABLE_CAT, 
SYNONYM_SCHEMA TABLE_SCHEM, SYNONYM_NAME as TABLE_NAME, TYPE_NAME AS TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_NAME TYPE_CAT, 
TYPE_NAME TYPE_SCHEM, TYPE_NAME AS TYPE_NAME, TYPE_NAME SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, TYPE_NAME REF_GENERATION,
NULL AS SQL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYNONYMS WHERE SYNONYM_CATALOG LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND SYNONYM_SCHEMA LIKE ?
ESCAPE ? AND SYNONYM_NAME LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND (false)  UNION SELECT TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEMA TABLE_SCHEM, 
TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_NAME TYPE_CAT, TYPE_NAME TYPE_SCHEM, TYPE_NAME, TYPE_NAME SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, 
TYPE_NAME REF_GENERATION, SQL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_CATALOG LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE ?
ESCAPE ? AND TABLE_NAME LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND (TABLE_TYPE IN(?)) ) 
ORDER BY TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME [42102-197] 42S02/42102 (Help)
```

Answer (score 7):

Please use version: h2-1.4.196 or h2-1.4.194.

Corda as of now uses version `ext.h2_version = '1.4.194'`.
The latest version of the driver is not compatible yet.

> Update:

With Corda 4 `ext.h2_version = '1.4.197'` so use appropriate version of h2 jar if using Corda 4.

Comment: Installing h2-1.4.196 didn't work for me, I haven't tried  h2-1.4.194 yet.

Comment: do try 194 because Corda uses the same version of H2.

Comment: also, use the web console only. Clients like Squirrel sometime throws an exception.

Comment: Turns out both 194 and 196 work for me when I start from the command line. I probably had an outstanding H2 session that I didn't kill and when I tried before. Running direct from the command line showed me the error and restarting my machine (force kill!) allowed the following to work: "java -jar h2-1.4.196.jar" - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get h2-1.4.194.jar (whichever version Corda is using) from Corda and place it in C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin

update h2.bat with h2-1.4.194.jar

it wont show the issue.. it worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with H2 all week, this just appeared to me as well. Has to be a bug. The console works as expected though, I was able to edit the database.

Answer (score 0):

java -jar h2-1.4.194.jar should work. Please check version is 1.4.194. Corda official site download (https://docs.corda.net/node-database.html) gives 1.4.197 version of H2 which doesn't work.