# Null pointer exception and Table "SYNONYMS" not found error in H2 console in corda

Tags: corda

I'm an newbie in `corda` and when I'm trying to execute the `corda` nodes, the nodes keep showing this error given below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase$ClassEntry.equals(MethodDatabase.java:557)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.recordSuspendableMethods(MethodDatabase.java:265)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:327)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.SimpleSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(SimpleSuspendableClassifier.java:156)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.DefaultSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(DefaultSuspendableClassifier.java:47)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.CheckInstrumentationVisitor.visitMethod(CheckInstrumentationVisitor.java:130)
> at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:347)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable0(MethodDatabase.java:194)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable(MethodDatabase.java:161)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentMethod.isSuspendableCall(InstrumentMethod.java:231)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor$1.visitMethodInsn(LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor.java:64)
> at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:123)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
> at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown
> Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown
> Source) [quasar] ERROR: java/lang/Thread
> java.lang.NullPointerException at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase$ClassEntry.equals(MethodDatabase.java:557)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.recordSuspendableMethods(MethodDatabase.java:265)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:327)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.SimpleSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(SimpleSuspendableClassifier.java:156)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.DefaultSuspendableClassifier.isSuspendable(DefaultSuspendableClassifier.java:47)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.CheckInstrumentationVisitor.visitMethod(CheckInstrumentationVisitor.java:130)
> at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkFileAndClose(MethodDatabase.java:347)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.checkClass(MethodDatabase.java:324)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.getOrLoadClassEntry(MethodDatabase.java:183)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable0(MethodDatabase.java:194)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.MethodDatabase.isMethodSuspendable(MethodDatabase.java:161)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentMethod.isSuspendableCall(InstrumentMethod.java:231)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor$1.visitMethodInsn(LabelSuspendableCallSitesClassVisitor.java:64)
> at co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source) at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:123)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.QuasarInstrumentor.instrumentClass(QuasarInstrumentor.java:94)
> at
> co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.JavaAgent$Transformer.transform(JavaAgent.java:209)
> at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
> java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown
> Source) at
> sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown
> Source)
```

After a while `corda` starts normally when ever I try to get to the `h2` console, the following error shows up:

```
Table "SYNONYMS" not found; SQL statement: SELECT TABLE_CAT,
> TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_CAT, TYPE_SCHEM, 
> TYPE_NAME, SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, REF_GENERATION, SQL FROM (SELECT
> SYNONYM_CATALOG TABLE_CAT,  SYNONYM_SCHEMA TABLE_SCHEM, SYNONYM_NAME
> as TABLE_NAME, TYPE_NAME AS TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_NAME TYPE_CAT, 
> TYPE_NAME TYPE_SCHEM, TYPE_NAME AS TYPE_NAME, TYPE_NAME
> SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, TYPE_NAME REF_GENERATION, NULL AS SQL FROM
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYNONYMS WHERE SYNONYM_CATALOG LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND
> SYNONYM_SCHEMA LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND SYNONYM_NAME LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND
> (false)  UNION SELECT TABLE_CATALOG TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEMA
> TABLE_SCHEM,  TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, REMARKS, TYPE_NAME TYPE_CAT,
> TYPE_NAME TYPE_SCHEM, TYPE_NAME, TYPE_NAME SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, 
> TYPE_NAME REF_GENERATION, SQL FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE
> TABLE_CATALOG LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND
> TABLE_NAME LIKE ? ESCAPE ? AND (TABLE_TYPE IN(?)) )  ORDER BY
> TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME [42102-197] 42S02/42102 (Help)
```

I tried to find an solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451741/browse-corda-database-tables-using-h2-web-interface-shows-synonyms-errors/49563959) but found out that `h2-1.4.194` was not available at their website. Is it an problem with my flow code, or is it a problem of plugin itself.

My flow code is given here `[https://ideone.com/Dy3nEM][2]`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For "SYNONYMS" not found error, using the latest version was the problem. so I have used the jar given by corda upon build, which will be situated in `\build\nodes\.cache\apps\net.corda.node.Corda_3.2-corda`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably missed a `@Suspebdable` annotation on one of your functions. The H2 error happened to me as well but couldn't fix. If you have Intellij Ultimate you could use their database browser which worked for me.

Comment: i have not missed an `@Suspendable` annotation actually. my flows code is in https://ideone.com/Dy3nEM. can you say where I went wrong

Comment: Not sure then, I'm concerned by the try catch, since you transaction could be null when calling `FinalityFlow`. Possible that this could be causing he exception. If it isn't, atleast the code will be more correct.